# Exclude page name from loop

Tags: loop, pages, tags

I'm currently using this loop:

```
if (is_single() || is_page() ) :
  if (have_posts() ) :
    while (have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
```

How can I exclude multiple pages within the loop?
For an example, I want to exclude pages `example.com/music` and `example.com/contact`.

EDIT:

I've done the way G.M provide, but my music and contact pages keeps loading after apply.

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_page() ) : if (have_posts() ) : $exclude_pages = array('music', 'contact'); while (have_posts() ) : if ( is_page() && ! empty($exclude_pages) && (
      in_array($post->post_name, (array)$exclude_pages) ||
      in_array($post->post_name, (array)$exclude_pages)
  ) ) continue; the_post(); ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php the_content_limit(150)?>" />
// loop continues
<?php endwhile; endif; 
elseif (is_home() ): ?>
// loop continues

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( is_page( 'music' )) { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
//loop continues
<?php } ?>
```

So to clarify:
I'd like to exclude some meta tags that i'm generating via a loop in the header.php
Now with my loop, all pages and post get affected by the loop.
So I don't want the pages music and contact to have the same header tags from the loop in header.php.

Comment: Could you clarify where you want to exclude the pages? And also, if you could give some context as to how this loop code is being used, that would help me understand exactly what is going on. Is this a standard WP page, or some custom functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Still not clear: in which file are you using this code? It is in the `page.php` or somewhere else? If this loop the main or are you using `query_posts` to generate a custom loop? The loop in the header, how is generated? with `WP_Query`, `query_posts` or `get_posts`?

Comment: No I'm not using this loop in page.php, I'm using it in the header.php (between <head></head>) file. What do you mean with how the loop is generated? The loop above is the complete loop code i've entered in the header.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way is putting the unwanted pages in an array. Useful for storing them in a option or in a serialized custom field.

```
$exclude_pages = array('music', 'contact');
// can be something like this: $exclude_pages = get_option('exclude_pages');

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  if ( is_page() && ! empty($exclude_pages) && (
      in_array($post->post_name, (array)$exclude_pages) ||
      in_array($post->post_title, (array)$exclude_pages)
  ) ) continue; // skip


  // the rest of your loop here
```

### Edit

To also exclude some post type you can use:

```
$exclude_pages = array('music', 'contact');
$exclude_post_types = array('music', 'any_here');

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  if ( is_page() && ! empty($exclude_pages) && (
    in_array($post->post_name, (array)$exclude_pages) ||
    in_array($post->post_title, (array)$exclude_pages)
  ) ||
  ( is_single() && in_array(get_post_type(), (array)$exclude_post_types) ) ) continue;
```

Comment: please see edit above in my question

Comment: thanks, your edited version works perfectly.
One more question, if I want to exclude a post template like single-music, would I then need to place the '$exclude_pages = array('single-music');' after ' if (have_posts() ) :' ?

Comment: @Eric see the edit

Answer (score 1):

[`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) will take a parameter for the page slug. That plus some logic operators should do it.

```
if (
  (is_single() || is_page())
  && (
    !is_page('music')
    || !is_page('contact')
  )
)
```

Note: it is very easy to get the logic wrong on these, and I didn't test that. It may not be quite right but I am sure it is close.

Comment: Why check for `is_single()` it never returns true for single page, if I'm not wrong. Maybe `is_singular()`, but why?

Comment: `is_single()` is `true` for single post/CPT pages. `is_singular()` is `true` for single page and single attachment types as well as for single post/CPT pages. `is_singular()` could probably stand in for some of that logic but the question description is minimal and the code is truncated. I am not really sure what the OP wants. Your answer is certainly a reasonable one, @g-m

Comment: Ah, ok. Problem is that, when I read *cpt* I always think it stands for custom *post* type. When I read page I always think at *default page post type*. So in my mind a *cpt page* does not exist only cpt *post*.